# Navigation Title does not center?

Tags: ios, xcode6, uinavigationitem

Quick question: the text of my Navigation Title does not center by default (unless I am running a 6 Plus), should it based on what type of phone it is displayed on?  The title shows up centered in the storyboard (using the Universal storyboard size), however, if I look on Preview or the actual phone (4S, 5, and 5S), the title is pushed all the way to the right.  Do I actually have to attempt to use AutoLayout or is there a setting in the Attribute Settings that I am missing?

[image]

Comment: How are you setting the title?

Comment: Storyboard -> Navigation Bar -> Navigation Item (set title here)

Comment: Please share your storboard screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without *Auto Layout*, the UI will appear in device/Simulator at exactly the same position as in storyboard, measured in points.

In storyboard, the scene is 600*600, and the title centers horizontally, so the horizontal ordinate of the title's center is 300, maybe at letter 'p'. Any iPhone earlier than 6/6Plus has the width of 320, as you can see in your screen shot, the right edge ends a little farther than 'p'.

*Auto Layout* can help you and in my experience it pays off to grasp it.

First, select Navigation Bar, then in the menu, choose Editor->Align->Horizontal Center in Container, that's all you have to do.

You will notice a warning arises, it won't bother you. You can ignore it until you understand *Auto Layout*.

I highly recommend [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/83129/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-swift-part-1)

Answer (score 5):

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 44);
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:frame];
label.text = @"Title Here";
self.navigationItem.titleView = label;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: ...and might actually get you some +1s

Answer (score 1):

It may be that you have wide bar button item/s in which case the title will be pushed off-center. For example this longish button name on an iPhone 4s pushes the title to the left. The same title / button name fits comfortably on a 6+ and centers as expected.

[image]

Comment: That is just it.  While I do have a button on the far left side (a Bar Button Item), it is not wide enough to push the title to the far right.  The Bar Button Item is an image (70px width) and I set the Bar Button Item width within the Size Inspector.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and it's the size classes next to Auto Layout that is causing the issue. If you disable it, it would appear centered. I am yet to find how to fix it with size classes on